# What is the meaning of Brahm Gyan?

Tags: vedas, brahma

What kind of knowledge is considered as **Brahm Gyan**? Is having knowledge of all four Vedas would make a person **Brahm Gyani**?

Does **Brahm** in **Brahm Gyan** denotes **Lord Brahma**? If so then what is the reason behind it?

Is there an example of anyone having **Brahm Gyan** in any epics like Ramayana, Mahabharata or any other?

Is this the highest level of gyan or is there another level higher?

Comment: Brahm Gyan is not the knowledge of 4 Vedas nor the knowledge of Brahma, the personified finite Brahman. One story is of Uddalaka instructing Shvetketu in Brahmgyan who learnt 4 Vedas without understanding the substratum Brahman. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38213/20656 .In short, the knowledge of Self, 'Who am I?' is the Brahm Gyan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The knowledge about Brahman is known as Brahman Gyan. Here Brahman doesn't mean the creator god Brahma. Brahman means the supreme entity from which all the beings originate, having originated in which all the beings remain and having remained at the end to which all the beings and things merge back into ( as per *yatova imani bhutani jayante...* Veda verse).

Having knowledge of all the Vedas can make one a pundit but not a Brahman Gyani. Moreover, the true knowledge and meaning of the Vedas is known to none but the Lord Himself (as per *vedanta krit vedavid eva chaham*... Gita verse).

In *Puranas* and mythology there have been examples of many Brahman Gyanis. Especially many sages were Brahma gyanis, but I the example of Uddhav I like the most who although was a Brahman Gyani, went on to mature to a next level of realising the supremacy of love for the Lord. Brahman gyana is not the highest level of gyana (although it is accepted as such by some *sampradaya* and sects) until the gyana of pure unconditional love for the Lord is there.

The Lord is above Brahman (as per *brahmano hi pratistha aham*.. Gita verse) and Brahman Gyan (as gyan or knowledge comes from Him as per matah smritir gyanam.. Gita verse) and unconditional love for Him is the Highest level.

To be honest, Brahman Gyan is not a thing of expression but personal experience. If the gyani thinks he knows Brahman, then he actually doesn't know It. (as per Kena Upanishad 2.1)